# Ask user to input a double instead of a String without making the program shutdown

Tags: java, string, double, shutdown

Hy, I wrote this piece of code where I'm asking the user to input a number:

```
public static double[] getscores()
{
int numscores=8;
double score[] = new double[numscores];
for (int a=0;a<numscores;a++)
{
Scanner ip=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a score");
score[a]=ip.nextDouble();
}
return score;
}
```

In the eventuality where the user accidentally enters a String, how am I supposed to tell him to input a number without making the program shut down? Thanks You

Comment: Have a read up on try...catch in Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A quick but "dirty" solution would be by using try-catch:

```
public static double[] getscores() {
    int numscores = 8;
    double score[] = new double[numscores];
    for (int a = 0; a < numscores; a++) {
        Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a score");
        try{
            score[a] = ip.nextDouble();
        } catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
            a--;
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Comment: That won't work. Using exception for flow control is a bad idea. Use `hasNextDouble()` instead. But the reason it doesn't work, is that `nextDouble()` doesn't consume the bad token when it fails, so it will loop forever. You also should create `Scanner` inside the loop.

Comment: It shows an error on the InputMismatchException saying: cannot find symbol-class InputMismatcheException

Comment: @AmadouToure You need to import `java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: @Amadou Toure: It may work like this, but keep in mind that this is just a quick and dirty hack. You should not construct your scanner in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch the exception thrown when the user doesn't input a `double`, ask the user to try again, and keep looping there until the user inputs a `double`. Alternatively, you can use `while(true)` and a `break` statement instea of a `do { ... } while`. Perhaps that is a bit shorter, but this is more readable.

Use a `BufferedReader` instead, because `Scanner` does not consume the input if it fails to parse it, so you'll get stuck in an infinite loop.

```
public static double[] getScores() throws IOException {
    final int NUM_SCORES = 8;
    double[] score = new double[NUM_SCORES];
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a score:");
        boolean isDouble = false;
        do {
            try {
                score[i] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                isDouble = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("You didn't enter a double. Please try again!");
            }
        } while (!isDouble);
    }
    br.close();
    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The user is *always* entering a String; `Scanner#nextDouble()` is a convenience method to interpret String input as a `double`.

Write a method that keeps reading input until a double is entered:

```
static double readDouble(Scanner scanner) {
    double score;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a score");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            score = Double.parseDouble(input);
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("'" + input + "' is not a valid score");
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

then call it from your loop:

```
score[a] = readDouble(ip);
```